# JavaMail Check GMail INBOX is taking too long to connect and answer back

Tags: jakarta-mail, gmail-api

I have a process that must check the INBOX on GMail for a failure message, it's working except for the problem of the time it takes to connect and check the message, it takes about 1 minute, that is too much time.

My code:

```
public static SendResult sendingSuccess(final String email) {
        SendResult result = new SendResult();
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
            props.setProperty("mail.imap.com", "993");
            props.setProperty("mail.imap.connectiontimeout", "5000");
            props.setProperty("mail.imap.timeout", "5000");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("imap.googlemail.com", 993, GMAIL_USER, GMAIL_PASSWORD);

            // Select and open folder
            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

            // What to search for
            SearchTerm searchTerm = new SearchTerm() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -7187666524976851520L;

                public boolean match(Message message) {
                    try {
                        String content = getContent(message);
                        boolean daemon = (message.getFrom()[0].toString()).contains("mailer-daemon@googlemail.com");
                        boolean failure = message.getSubject().contains("Failure");
                        boolean foundWarning = content.contains(email);
                        if (daemon && failure && foundWarning) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };

            // Fetch unseen messages from inbox folder
            Message[] messages = inbox.search(searchTerm);

            // If there is no message then it's OK
            result.setStatus(messages.length == 0);
            result.setMessage(result.isStatus() ? "No failure message found for " + email : "Failure message found for " + email);

            // Flag message as DELETED
            for (Message message : messages) {
                message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
            }

            // disconnect and close
            inbox.close(false);
            store.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            result.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

When I run this code to query the failure message it takes more than 1 minute to return the result to me.

```
======= Checking Gmail account for message failure! =====
Start...: 09:00:33
Finish..: 09:01:01
Result..: SendResult [status=true, message=No failure found for wrong.user@gmxexexex.net]
```

Is there any way to reduce this time?

Comment: Just to confirm, isn't it just 28 seconds?

Comment: Yes, but that is too much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely because you've written your own search term.  JavaMail doesn't know how to translate your search term into an IMAP SEARCH request so it executes the search on the client, which requires downloading all the messages to the client to search there.  Try this instead:

```
    SearchTerm searchTerm = new AndTerm(new SearchTerm[] {
            new FromStringTerm("mailer-daemon@googlemail.com"),
            new SubjectTerm("Failure"),
            new BodyTerm(email)
    });
```

That will allow the search to be done by the IMAP server.